# How to print from the in-built Printer in Android POS using the SDK?

Tags: java, android, thermal-printer, point-of-sale

Can someone kindly put me on the right direction to implement a print functionality on android POS device using the given SDK?

I am working on an application for an Android POS device that have a built in line printer. I have to interact with this printer and use it to print the details on receipt. I have the JAR SDK file and the documentation but can't seem to understand how to go about it.

I have successfully imported the `JAR` file into my project root. I want to implement a test print but don't know how to go about it. Please kindly guide me. Thanks

Comment: Unless the SDK and its documentation is publicly available, you are better off asking the POS manufacturer for support/tutorials.

Comment: If I can get an arbitrary example of the implementation with any publicly available SDK, I can follow suit to implement mine. I just need an heads up.

Comment: a  are you find sdk in-build printer ? please share with me thanks